# Change language text on a spinner based on enum

Tags: android, enums

I am developing an application with an enum to populate a spinner and pictures associated with them. When I try to refer spinner texts to strings.xml to get the spinner populated with texts in the language set on the phone, I only get numbers instead of texts. getNombres() is used to populate the spinner in the Main Activity.

Here is the code:

```
 public enum TipoLugar {
     OTROS(R.string.otros, R.drawable.otros),
     RESTAURANTE(R.string.restaurante ,R.drawable.restaurante),
     BAR(R.string.restaurante , R.drawable.bar),
     COPAS(R.string.copas , R.drawable.copas),
     ESPECTACULO(R.string.restaurante , R.drawable.espectaculos),
     HOTEL(R.string.hotel , R.drawable.hotel),
     COMPRAS(R.string.compras , R.drawable.compras),
     EDUCACION( R.string.educacion ,R.drawable.educacion),
     DEPORTE(R.string.deporte , R.drawable.deporte),
     NATURALEZA(R.string.naturaleza , R.drawable.naturaleza),
     GASOLINERA(R.string.gasolinera , R.drawable.gasolinera),
     VIVIENDA(R.string.vivienda , R.drawable.vivienda),
     MONUMENTO( R.string.monumento ,R.drawable.monumento);
     private final int texto;
     private final int recurso;

     TipoLugar(int texto,int recurso) {

         this.texto = texto;
         this.recurso = recurso;
       }

     public String getTexto() {
         return String.valueOf(texto);
     }

     public int getRecurso() {
         return recurso;
     }

     public static String[] getNombres() {
         String[] resultado = new String[TipoLugar.values().length];
         for (TipoLugar tipo : TipoLugar.values()) {
             resultado[tipo.ordinal()] = String.valueOf(tipo.texto);
         }
         return resultado;
     } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TWO WAYS:**
First remove the static key word from your method if it is in `MainActivity` and change your method into:

```
public String[] getNombres() {
     String[] resultado = new String[TipoLugar.values().length];
     for (TipoLugar tipo : TipoLugar.values()) {
         resultado[tipo.ordinal()] = getString((tipo.texto));
     }
     return resultado;
 }
```

Second way is to keep the static word but now you have to pass the `Context` each time you want to call your method:

```
public static String[] getNombres(Context context) {
     String[] resultado = new String[TipoLugar.values().length];
     for (TipoLugar tipo : TipoLugar.values()) {
         resultado[tipo.ordinal()] = context.getString((tipo.texto));
     }
     return resultado;
 }
```

And you will call your method this way in your `MainActivity`:

```
getNombres(this);
```

From here you will get `String`s instead of `int`s because you will get String values from the Strings!

Comment: Thank you very much. I did your second proposal and worked perfectly

Comment: Okay @spcarman you are welcome. But there is one thing left to do accept my answer because it solved your problem (stackoverflow style). Click tick sign on the left of the answer! You are the only one who can do that because you asked the question! **Happy Coding!**.